# NextJS - Sending cookies to API server from getInitialProps

Tags: node.js, laravel, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using NextJS as a client side repository to talk to my backend API server (laravel). Auth is done via JWT stored in the cookies. It all works seamlessly when I send an auth request to `https://my-backend-server.com/api/login`, as I respond with a cookie, and set to the my-backend-server.com domain. And even when I send requests from the browser.

Problems arise when I want to load the page, and sent the request from getInitialProps, as this is a serverside call. How am I able to access the cookies to `my-backend-server.com`, and put those in the header, so the server-side request from NextJS is properly authorized?

Most of the answers say something about `req.cookies` or `req.headers.cookies`, however this is empty as the request in getInitialProps is to `http://my-local-clientside-site.com`

Answer (score 6):

As you explained correctly, Next's `getInitialProps` is called on **client** & on **server**.

If your Next app & Api services are served from the **same domain**, your Api service can put the cookie on the domain, and it will work on the client side (browser).

Whenever your Next app accessing the api from server-side, you need to attach the cookie by yourself.

`getInitialProps` method on the server side gets on the context (first param) the request (as `req`) from the browser, that means that this request has the **cookie**.

If you have a custom server, you probably need add to it a [cookieParser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser),

```js
// server.js

import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import express from 'express';
import next from 'next';

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const nextHandler = app.getRequestHandler();

  const server = express();

  server.use(cookieParser());
  // -----------^

  server.get('*', (req, res) => nextHandler(req, res));
});
```

This parser will parse the `Cookie` header and put it as an object on the `req`.

After that, your `req.cookie` should have the cookie value (make sure that you see that the browser sends it in the document request) you can access it in your `getInitialProps`,

```
//pages/index.js

const IndexPage = () => <div>BLA</div>

IndexPage.getInitialProps = (context) => {
  if(context.req) {
    // it runs on server side
    axios.defaults.headers.get.Cookie = context.req.headers.cookie;
  }
};
```

I've given you an example that sets up axios to put the cookie on all requests that will be made from the client.

Answer (score -3):

Felixmosh' answer is half correct. rather than context.req.cookie it should be context.req.headers.cookie.

```
const IndexPage = () => <div>BLA</div>

IndexPage.getInitialProps = (context) => {
  if(context.req) {
    // it runs on server side
    axios.defaults.headers.get.Cookie = context.req.headers.cookie;
    //make api call with axios - it would have correct cookies to authenticate your api call
  }
};
```